# TOAD : force DB user to change password at next login

Tags: oracle, toad

This is very easy to achieve in SQL Developer, but somehow I cannot find this option in TOAD.

I created a new user, set him a password and now I want to force him to change the password at first logon, due to security policy. Any idea how to do that using GUI / sql statement?

Thanks,
Danijel

Comment: Use SQL command: `ALTER USER username PASSWORD EXPIRE;` it's very easy too and works on all clients (toad, slqplus, sql-developer, dbaver .......).

Comment: Will that force use to change password when he logs in?

Comment: I just tried : yes it does work, the solution you provided is great, thanks a lot. Just one unimportant thing : is this possible to achieve using GUI?

Comment: `is this possible to achieve using GUI?` - hard to say, it depends on GUI creator, you must refer to your GUI documentation => http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/w/toad_for_oracle_wiki/10496.toad-for-oracle-documentation  I prefer SQL command , it's independent from any GUI.

Answer (score 1):

open Toad==>Database==>Schema Browser==>swift to User==>right click Alter User
.There is a gui oponion for password expired.Hope useful to you .